# Keycloak + spring cloud gateway + authentication and authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to use keycloak for authentication and also authorization in the spring cloud gateway itself. But I'm getting the below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [poc/apigateway/SecurityConfig.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: 
Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
clientRegistrationRepository cannot be null
```

My application.properties

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway

spring.cloud.gateway.default-filters=TokenRelay

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=product-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8009
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/product

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].id=order-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].uri=http://localhost:8008
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[1].predicates[0]=Path=/api/order

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.keycloak.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/microservice-realm
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.client-id=spring-cloud-gateway-client
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.client-secret=d1b3670c-f1c3-480c-9cda-8e107aec7d5b
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.scope=openid, profile, roles
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.spring-cloud-gateway-client.redirect-uri=http://localhost:8005/login/oauth2/code/spring-cloud-gateway-client

spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/microservice-realm

keycloak.realm=microservice-realm
keycloak.resource=spring-cloud-gateway-client
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8080/auth
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=app-user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/api/*
```

My build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.4'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'poc'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.3")
    set('keycloakVersion', '4.8.3.Final')
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-gateway'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    // Keycloak
    implementation 'org.keycloak:keycloak-spring-boot-starter'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:${keycloakVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

My SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults());
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The issue comes when the application is booting up. What I'm trying to do here is do the authentication and role bases authorization in the API gateway itself.

Answer (score 9):

The Keycloak adapter doesn't work with WebFlux, only with MVC, so you should remove this dependency:

```
mavenBom "org.keycloak.bom:keycloak-adapter-bom:${keycloakVersion}"
```

You can use

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

and configure the Keycloak as the Oauth server:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            provider: keycloak
            client-id: web
            client-secret: '{cipher}xxxx'
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            authorization-uri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
            token-uri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
            user-info-uri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
            jwk-set-uri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
            user-name-attribute: name
            user-info-authentication-method: header
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
keycloak-client:
  server-url: https://keycloakURL/auth
  realm: your-realm
```

And the FilterChain:

```
  @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers(constraintsConfig.getOpenUri())
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated()
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
```